# Converte VBA para usar no Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Preciso converter o código abaixo para usar no google Sheets. Alguem poderia ajudar.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Range("B4").Sort Key1:=Range("b5"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

End Sub
```